# ORO CRM Edit Marketing List

Tags: javascript, php, datagrid, frontend, orocrm

I have a problem with the marketing list edition in OroCRM.
Since I updated Google Chrome (and Firefox) to the latest version, I cannot see the fields in the datagrid list marketing when I want to edit them.

There should be the fields first selected when I created the marketing list.

> [image: screenshot]

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Which version of OroCRM do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue that i[s already fixed in a development branch](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/commit/8466a5360d94ab5addb3dbebefdff4e1281ffdfb). The application release with the fix is going to be available till the end of the week.

Comment: Hello Andrey, thank you very much for your response, so I have fix this with a patch.